# NodeJS/Javascript: Access variable from function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to access variables inside two of my functions but I'm not getting back anything. What am I doing wrong & how can I fix it?

---

So here's what my code looks like:

```
exports.show = function(req, res) {
    var next_id;
    var prev_id;
    Article.find({'created':{$gt:req.article.created}}).sort('-created').limit(1).exec(function(err, articles) {
        if (!err && articles[0] !== undefined) {
            next_id = articles[0].id; // trying to get this variable
        }

    });

    Article.find({'created':{$lt:req.article.created}}).sort('-created').limit(1).exec(function(err, articles) {
        if (!err && articles[0] !== undefined) {
            prev_id = articles[0].id; // and this variable
        }

    });

    res.jsonp({article : req.article, next_href : next_id, prev_href : prev_id});

};
```

Comment: Is `Article.find` asynchronous?

Comment: @thefourtheye I'm really not sure (I'm new to NodeJS & still a novice in Javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @thefourtheye.  It's likely async.  You can use an async library, such as *node-async* or a *promise* library.  But in this case, if you wanted to do it without a library, you'd simply have to nest your methods to make sure that the next step only executes once the previous step finishes.

```
exports.show = function(req, res) {
    var next_id;
    var prev_id;
    Article.find({'created':{$gt:req.article.created}}).sort('-created').limit(1).exec(function(err, articles) {
        if (!err && articles[0] !== undefined) {
            next_id = articles[0].id; // trying to get this variable
        }

        Article.find({'created':{$lt:req.article.created}}).sort('-created').limit(1).exec(function(err, articles) {
            if (!err && articles[0] !== undefined) {
                prev_id = articles[0].id; // and this variable
            }

            res.jsonp({article : req.article, next_href : next_id, prev_href : prev_id});
        });

    });

};
```

So step 1 is to lookup the next_id.  When the `exec` method is called (after the async request) you can then move on to step 2, which is looking up the prev_id.  When that `exec` method is called, you know you're done and can return the value, `res.jsonp(...)`.

An async library would be useful here because this method makes things run iteratively, which means the second request (prev_id) won't start until the first request (next_id) completes.  You can run async requests in parallel and wait for BOTH requests to finish and then set your `res.jsonp` response.  [Here's a sample article using node-async](http://justinklemm.com/node-js-async-tutorial/)

Comment: Yep, that's actually what I decided to do but wanted to wait just in case there was a better way. Also, thx for the async link